# Parsing a JSON array of values as POJOs

Tags: java, json, jackson

I need to process responses from an external SAP service which returns data as an array of arrays like this:

```
{
    "INFO":"",
    "SERVICE_NAME":[["PARAM1","PARAM2","PARAM3","PARAM4"]],
    "RESULTS":[
        ["object1fieldValue1","object1fieldValue2"],
        ["object2fieldValue1","object2fieldValue2"]
    ]
}
```

I would like to process the RESULTS further as a list of DTOs like this:

```
public class ResultItemDto {
    private String field1;
    private String field2;
}
```

instead of working with every object as a list of Strings and possibly mapping it manually to DTOs.

What would be the right, concise "Jackson way" of mapping such JSON directly to POJOs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can annotate a class with `@JsonFormat` to indicate that it will appear as an array in JSON:

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.ARRAY)
class ResultItemDto {
    private String field1;
    private String field2;
}
```

To verify the above I created a wrapper class for the full object:

```
class ResultWrapper {
    private List<ResultItemDto> results;
}
```

And deserialize like this:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
mapper.enable(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES);

ResultWrapper result = mapper.readValue(json, ResultWrapper.class);
```

Where `ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES` is used because your JSON has fields with upper case names.

Documentation for [@JsonFormat](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonFormat.html) and pertinent [shapes](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonFormat.Shape.html)

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, @JsonFormat is for serialization only.  This question in its current form is asking for deserialization.

Comment: @whaley although the `@JsonFormat` docs link mentions serialization only, it's also used for deserialization and is listed for both purposes on [Jackson's list of annotations](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations/wiki/Jackson-Annotations#deserialization-and-serialization-details). In any case, I have actually tested the code above and it works as advertised.

Comment: Brilliant, exactly what I was hoping for. I just used it and also can confirm that it works for deserialization. Thanks!

Comment: I was even able to use custom deserializer via `@JsonDeserialize` on `ResultItemDto` fields, but this forced me to use `@JsonPropertyOrder` - for some reason when using the deserializer mapper is reading the n+1 property instead of n-th one with `@JsonDeserialize`.

Answer (score 1):

The "right" way is very subjective, but since you were curious about a concise way, your options are limited given that the fields you want access to are contained within arrays of arrays.  Given this structure, mapping directly via annotations and without using custom deserializers is going to be out of the question.  Your two options for custom parsing are the databind api and the streaming api.  The databind API tends to be a bit easier to read and write, so we'll use that to fulfill your requirements of conciseness

Below is some code that uses an ObjectReader to parse the json tree and then safely uses JsonNode's `path`, `isArrayNode`, and `asText` methods to pluck out the values of those inner arrays if they are where expected, and will not result in an exception if the json you receive is in a different structure.  This assumes you want to throw away the rest of the JSON body, as your question only discusses mapping specifically to the ResultItemDto.

```
package foo.bar;


import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ArrayNode;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {

    static final String JSON = "{\n" +
                                       "    \"INFO\":\"\",\n" +
                                       "    \"SERVICE_NAME\":[[\"PARAM1\",\"PARAM2\",\"PARAM3\",\"PARAM4\"]],\n" +
                                       "    \"RESULTS\":[\n" +
                                       "        [\"object1fieldValue1\",\"object1fieldValue2\"],\n" +
                                       "        [\"object2fieldValue1\",\"object2fieldValue2\"]\n" +
                                       "    ]\n" +
                                       "}";

    static class ResultItemDto {
        private String field1;
        private String field2;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        List<ResultItemDto> list = new ArrayList<ResultItemDto>();

        ObjectReader reader = new ObjectMapper().reader();
        JsonNode resultsNode = reader.readTree(JSON).path("RESULTS");
        if (resultsNode.isArray()) {
            ArrayNode arrNode = (ArrayNode) resultsNode;
            arrNode.elements().forEachRemaining(elem -> {
                ResultItemDto dto = new ResultItemDto()
                dto.field1 = elem.path(0).asText();
                dto.field2 = elem.path(1).asText();
                list.add(dto);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

If you wanted to annotate your DTO class, the above code could be used inside of a custom deserializer once you've annotated the dto with `@JsonDeserialize` and can call the `readTree` method on the JsonParser you must use when deserializing.